# Accessibility for a Draggable, Droppable and Sortable component

Tags: accessibility, drag-n-drop, sorting

This is a component that I'm trying to make accessible:

[image]

As I understand, the ARIA Authoring Practices guidelines for drag and drop is basically:

1. <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move through the list of items
2. <kbd>Space</kbd> to select an item
3. Arrow keys to switch between the dropzone(s)
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd> to Drop

.. which works fine to get the items within the drop zone, but I wonder how should the `sortable` work?

Comment: Are the guidelines you've mentioned really standards? Seems highly non-standard. Could you provide a reference link, please?

Comment: Updated question to reflect the correct accessibility keys set by WAI-ARIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [W3.org site](https://www.w3.org/blog/wai-components-gallery/widget/accessible-drag-and-drop/) gives [an accessible drag-and-drop example](https://dev.opera.com/articles/accessible-drag-and-drop/example.html) that offers the following key controls:

- Use the Tab to move to the item you want to move.
- Select the item you want to move with the Spacebar.
- Use the Up and Down cursor keys to select a target in the context menu.
- Press Enter to move the item to the target list.

From this it's not difficult to extract the following controls for your situation:

- Use Tab to move between items
- Use space to select an item
- Use enter to move it between lists (add or remove)
- Use arrow keys to move an item within a list